# Multidimension Array Reading From Text

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a sample example from a text file, however, my arrays are not indexing the proper strings and I dont know how to fix it. The output returns nulls. Can I get some direction?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\andre\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ArrayExample2\\src\\Question1");
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file); // have to throw an exception

    String[] questions = new String[10];
    String[] answers = new String[4];
    String[][] choices = new String[10][4];//3 questions 4 possible answers

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        questions[i] = fileScanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(questions[i]);
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            System.out.println(choices[i][k]);
        }

        String choicesInALine = fileScanner.nextLine();
        String[] choiceItems = choicesInALine.split("#");
        //transfer items with for loop

        for (int j = 0; j < choiceItems.length; j++) {
            choices[i][j] = choiceItems[j];
        }

        answers[i] = fileScanner.nextLine();
    }

    fileScanner.close();

    ...
```

// Text File

```
Psychology and Science
85
By the 1920s a new definition of psychology had gained favor. Psychology was said to be the science of...
mind # consciousness # computers # behavior # philosophy
```

etc..

Comment: try sorting out your identation

Comment: What's the behaviour you're seeing, and what do you expect your output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

You have three questions, however you are taking input in `questions` array 10 times in the loop. Also you have taken no input in `choices` array. You are directly printing `choices` array which is giving null values:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    questions[i] = fileScanner.nextLine(); // questions array will contains questions and options
    System.out.println(questions[i]);
    for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        System.out.println(choices[i][k]); // You have taken no input in choices.
                                           //It will give null values
    }
}
```

You must take input in `choices` array first & then print its values.